# Recursion reaches a non-void, binary search tree

Tags: c++

I get the warning that it reaches an end of non-void function. It's supposed to search in the binary search tree. And return SUCCESS if it found the desirable.
What can I do to fix it?

```
TREEResult FindInBST(Node<T>* node,int key, void** value,int treeSize)
    {
        if(node!=NULL && node->key==key)
        {
            *value=node->data;
            return SUCCESS;
        }
        if(treeSize==0)
        {
            return FAILURE;
        }
        if(node->key<key)
        {   treeSize--;
            FindBST(node->rightSon,key,value,treeSize);
        }
        else
        {   treeSize--;
            FindBST(node->LeftSon,key,value,treeSize);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You promise to return a `TREEResult` but don't in the two recursive calls. Thankfully the compiler is warning about this because it is Undefined Behavior to break this rule. You probably need to change `FindBST(node->rightSon,key,value,treeSize);` to `return FindBST(node->rightSon,key,value,treeSize);` and `FindBST(node->LeftSon,key,value,treeSize);` to `return FindBST(node->LeftSon,key,value,treeSize);`

Comment: How can I cover all the conditions? @SamVarshavchik

Comment: @drescherjm can you please explain why it makes a difference?

Comment: Let me search for a duplicate. Failing to return from a non void function should be a common cause of bugs / crashes and other Undefined Behavior.

Comment: It makes a difference because code calling your function can not trust the return value if some of the calls can return random garbage as the return code. On top of this it is undefined behavior so the effect can be more than just returning a garbage code. It can crash your program or cause other random behavior.

Comment: Recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions. If you're supposed to return something, you need to do that. There's no "magic" that returns the result of the last function call for you if you don't do it yourself.

Comment: That is a good point. The compiler will not collect the last returned value and ignore function calls that don't return a value. Every function call must return a value otherwise its Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You promise to return a `TREEResult` but don't in the two recursive calls. Thankfully the compiler is warning about this because it is Undefined Behavior to break this rule.

To fix this you need to change:

```
FindBST(node->rightSon,key,value,treeSize);
```

to

```
return FindBST(node->rightSon,key,value,treeSize);
```

and also

```
FindBST(node->LeftSon,key,value,treeSize);
```

to

```
return FindBST(node->LeftSon,key,value,treeSize);
```

As @molbdnilo mentioned in the comments there is no "magic" in recursive calls versus non recursive ones.  ***If you're supposed to return something, you need to do that.***

failure to return a value is Undefined Behavior.

The value that these recursive calls return will propagate from one of the SUCCESS or FAILURE results returned from your base case depending on if the search found or did not find the item.